# Issue while trying to replace url in javascript due to special chars

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I need to replace a value in a template using js, but I'm having a problem because there is a "$" char in this url that is messing up with everything.

Here is the code sample:

```js
var url = "http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/LuxotticaRetail/8053672035704_shad_fr?$jpegdefault$&wid=45"
var template = '<img class="thumb-img" src="{{image_thumb}}">';

template = template.replace(/\{\{image_thumb\}\}/g, url);

console.log(template);
```

as a result I'm getting this:

> `http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/LuxotticaRetail/8053672035704_shad_fr?$jpegdefault{{image_thumb}}wid=45`

As you can see the value that should have been replaced is in the middle of the string: `{{image_thumb}}`.

Do you know some way I could do to make this replace "ignore" the $ and keep the url as it should be?

I tried to use `encodeURIComponent()` but it changes other values of the url I don't want to be changed..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, guys.

I found a simple and easy solution:

```
template = template.replace(/\{\{image_thumb\}\}/g, function(){ return url });
```

This way the url is kept and the replace works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

> **Syntax :** RegExp['$&']
>
> **Description :** The lastMatch property is static, it is not a property of an individual regular expression object. Instead, you always use it as RegExp.lastMatch or RegExp['$&'].

So please not that you have `$&` in your string and you use it in `replace` function that use regex expresions :

```
template = template.replace(/\{\{image_thumb\}\}/g, url);
```

So the `$&` in your string will be translated to **lastMatch property** that will print `{{image_thumb}}` instead of `$&`, That why you get :

```
<img class="thumb-img" src="http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/LuxotticaRetail/8053672035704_shad_fr?$jpegdefault{{image_thumb}}wid=45">
```

---

Simple example :

```
var url = "http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/LuxotticaRetail/8053672035704_shad_fr?$jpegdefault$&wid=45"
var template = '<img class="thumb-img" src="{{image_thumb}}">';

template = template.replace(/\{\{image_thumb\}\}/g, 'some $& text');

console.log(template);

//will return
<img class="thumb-img" src="some {{image_thumb}} text">
```

**So you have to eliminate the expression `$&` from your `url`.**

**[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't touch the url because it is not generated by me... but I think I found a solution.. I'll publish it here

Answer (score 0):

To make the replace function ignore the $, remove it first.

```
url = url.replace(/\$//g);
```

Comment: I cannot remove the $ from the url.. it should be kept :/